# I am not able to check for the data types for parameter, which I am passing through postman

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, rest

This method is to save both parent and child :

```
public Response createMultipleChilds(PurchaseOrderHeader purchaseOrderHeader){

       try {
           s=sf.openSession();
           tx=s.beginTransaction();
        createParent(purchaseOrderHeader);
        for(int i=0;i<purchaseOrderHeader.getPurchaseItemList().size();i++){

        purchaseOrderHeader.getPurchaseItemList().get(i).setHeaderDetails(purchaseOrderHeader);
        createChild(purchaseOrderHeader.getPurchaseItemList().get(i));
        }
         response.setStatus(200);
        response.setMessage(" both added succesfull");
        if(tx.isActive()){
            tx.commit();  }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
        response.setStatus(500);
        response.setMessage("parent not added");
        tx.rollback();

    }finally{
        s.close();
    }
    return response;

   }
```

This is method is called to save the parent attributes :

```
private void createParent(PurchaseOrderHeader purchaseOrderHeader) {
        try {
            s=sf.openSession();
            tx=s.beginTransaction();
        PurchaseOrderHeader order=new PurchaseOrderHeader();
        if(purchaseOrderHeader.getCompany_code() instanceof String)
        order.setCompany_code(purchaseOrderHeader.getCompany_code());
        if(purchaseOrderHeader.getCurrency() instanceof String)
        order.setCurrency(purchaseOrderHeader.getCurrency());
        if(purchaseOrderHeader.getStatus() instanceof String)
        order.setStatus(purchaseOrderHeader.getStatus());
        if(purchaseOrderHeader.getVendor() instanceof String)
        order.setVendor(purchaseOrderHeader.getVendor());

        order.setPurchaseItemList(null);
        order.setDocument_number(purchaseOrderHeader.getDocument_number());
            s.save(order);
             response.setStatus(200);
            response.setMessage(" parent added succesfull");
            if(tx.isActive()){
                tx.commit();  }     
            } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
            response.setStatus(500);
            response.setMessage("parent not added");
            tx.rollback();
        }
        finally{
            s.close();
        }
    }
```

This method is called to store child :

```
private void createChild(PurchaseItem purchaseItem) {

        try {
            s=sf.openSession();
            tx=s.beginTransaction();
            PurchaseItem item=new PurchaseItem();
            if(purchaseItem.getItemName() instanceof String)
            item.setItemName(purchaseItem.getItemName());
            if(purchaseItem.getItemPrice() instanceof String)
            item.setItemPrice(purchaseItem.getItemPrice());
            item.setHeaderDetails(purchaseItem.getHeaderDetails());
            s.save(item);
             response.setStatus(200);
            response.setMessage(" child added succesfull");
            if(tx.isActive()){
                tx.commit();  }}
            catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
            response.setStatus(500);
            response.setMessage("child not added");
            tx.rollback();
        }
        finally{
            s.close();
        }
    }
```

The method  is storing both parent and child, But it is not validating(means when I pass int value instead of string.It is getting stored even though I am checking for the data type)

Comment: When you use double codes in the json structure that will be treated as string instead of int.

Comment: I am not using double quotes but still it is getting stored                                        
 :[{ "itemName":"sample", "itemPrice":12000 }.                                             here "itemprice" is string and i am giving int value but still it is getting stored

Comment: I have no idea why it is happening like that.Why dont you use JAXB marshall & unmarshall .https://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/ https://howtodoinjava.com/jaxb/read-xml-to-java-object/

Comment: Ok thanks for the suggestion